# How to get user input with UITextView in different cells in UITableVIew

Tags: swift, xcode, textview, tableview

so I have a `UITableView` and within each cell, a `UITextView`. I want the user to be able to edit each `UITextView` as many times as they like, then go back to somewhere else in the app, close the app, whatever, and then come back and see the same thing they wrote. I have not been able to figure out how to do it.

Please help. I'm still pretty new to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design problem. Anyway my suggestion is to add a flag in your data model.

Data model (the data that you are presenting in your table). If you don't have any data model, add one.

Example:

```
class UserInformation {
  name: String
  isEditing: Bool = false
}
```

and then save this in your preferred location either in DB (core data, realm etc) or plist (which i don't recommend)

now during the creation of cell. You could just check if this is in editing mode. And then fill up the text field using the saved data.

EDIT: You can't just magically know/retain a state in an object without persisting.

Comment: What do you mean a design problem?

Comment: An app architectural problem. It all depends on how you implement/design/architect your application. One of the possible solution is the one that I said.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store textView informations in any case, including terminating application, there are some steps to implement this feature.

At first, you have to pick up a place for storing your information:

- Hard disk
- Your own server
- Other service (firebase ...)

RAM is not useable in this case.

Supposing you like hard disk option, let's select a method for storing:

- Create a file (JSON, text file, ...), save your information every time user enter a new one, open it to get information back.
- Save it by CoreData / Realm in database way (CoreData is like SQL lite, a lite weight database for mobile application supported by Apple)